# Get SMS content from intent

Tags: nativescript

I try to get the content of a sms from an intent but so far without any success.
I can see the messege bundel, and the pdus but i can't understant how to extract the content in some human readble format.

Here is my code:

```
 Application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(
  'android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED',
  (context, intent: android.content.Intent) => {
    console.log("SMS Recived");
    const pdus = intent.getExtras().get("pdus");

    //HOW TO EXTRACT THE MESSAGE HERE?
  }
```

When i tried to do it like in android i am getting an error

```
const pdus = intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
android.telephony.SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdus);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end i solve the problem by bumping up the sdk from 17 to a version that telephony.sms exists and used another function to get the intent data.

```
(context, intent: android.content.Intent) => {
  const msgs = android.provider.Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent);
  const msg = msgs[0];
  const sender = msg.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
  const content = msg.getDisplayMessageBody();
}
```

if someone has another slution without bumping the sdk version i would be happy to see